# Receipt Validation / IAP

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am following this tutorial in order to see how `Receipt Validation` works when using IAP.

[In-App Purchases: Receipt Validation Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9257-in-app-purchases-receipt-validation-tutorial)

At some point in the provided trial project this code appears:

```
  func refreshReceipt() {
    verificationStatus.text = "Requesting refresh of receipt."
    verificationStatus.textColor = .green
    print("Requesting refresh of receipt.")
    let refreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
    refreshRequest.delegate = self
    refreshRequest.start()
  }
```

And since the app hits a problem when I run it on my own device and tap on `Refresh Receipt`:

It shows in red:

```
The operation couldn't be completed (SSE...
```

After showing in green for about half a second:

```
Requesting refresh of receipt.
```

I have put a break point in the function above and try to see what is happening.

But I can't find the place where the message is fired and can't figure out what I need to do to fix the issue. I am not particularly expecting anything, but I would like to understand what is happening where and this is not the case at this point.

Anyone has already tried this same tutorial and has mastered it?
Some hints would be very helpful.

For example: is there some spot in the code where I should put a break point to see what is happening?

Comment: You must be setting the `textColor` to `.red` somewhere - it shouldn't be too hard to find.  Presumably in `request(_:didFailWithError:)`.  You need to see the full text of the error.  It seems that it is too long for the label and is being truncated on the screen.

Comment: Maybe you don't have a receipt on the device? Are you sure the receipt isn't null? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1407276-appstorereceipturl

Comment: @Paulw11. Yes. Thanks. I indeed found it after posting. I looked for "verificationStatus.text" and it worked. I was first looking for "The operation couldn't be completed" ... and that didn't make it.

Comment: @enc_life. Indeed I did not have a receipt, but that was not the issue. I only wanted to find out where the message was coming from in the program.